# Issue with setContentView() in AsyncTask on fragment view

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I was trying to build a typical `ListView` using the default fragment view in Android - so I need to use `setContentView()` first to after get the appropriate `ListView` in that layout. However, I keep getting this error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   setContentView(int) from the type Activity

I understand this error but do not know how to fix it here (I cannot just go and transform it to static). I am sure my layout name is correct (`R.layout.menuList`). I am executing this in an `AsyncTask` under the `onPostExecute()` section (so it is the same thread as the UI). What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you add the code to your post?

Answer (score 1):

*My first thought:* Although you've not mentioned but since its complaining about `static` reference, I assume that you are trying `YourActivity.setContentView(R.layout.menuList);` ?
Instead try using `YourActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.menuList);`. You need correct `context`.